# How to apply normalize-space to xpath?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I want to apply a normalisation function to the result as follows:

```
r = response.xpath('.//dt[@class="information-list__item__definition__item__term"]/text()').getall()
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
r = response.xpath(normalize-space('.//dt[@class="information-list__item__definition__item__term"]/text()')).getall()
```

It didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You are performing it on a list due to the fact that you've used **getall(**)

You need to reorganize your code so that you can work with **get()** and that will allow you to use normalize-space.

[normalize-space demo video](https://youtu.be/2XSbV1_yaak?t=105)